# How do I suppress flow symbol errors?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, flowtype

I'm trying to create type definition in Flow for one of my objects. I'm not sure whether Flow support `Symbols`, but in such cases how could I skip this warning?

```
 const version: Version = this.getVersion(12345);
 const upLink: string = version[Symbol.for('__my_amazing_symbol')];
```

But on validating the line above, I have the following error on run `flow check`.

```
Error: src/local.js:197
197:               const upLink: string = version[Symbol.for('__my_amazing_symbol')];
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ access of computed property/element. Computed property cannot be accessed with
197:               const upLink: string = version[Symbol.for('__my_amazing_symbol')];
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Symbol


Found 2 errors
```

This is my type of such object.

```
declare export type Version = {
        name: string;
        version: string;
    };
```

Flow config

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
lib/.*

[include]

[libs]
node_modules/@mod/types/lib/

[lints]

[options]
suppress_comment= \\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe
unsafe.enable_getters_and_setters=true

[version]
^0.52.0
```

Comment: did you try // $FlowFixMe before the line, i'm seeing it in your config

Comment: also please edit your question title, should be : how do I suppress flow symbol errors ?

Comment: The // $FlowFixMe should be the valid answer. :)  It works for me. I'll update the title thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the type error has anything to do with `Symbol` per-se. What Flow is telling you is that you declared the `Version` type with keys `name` and `version`, but now you're looking up a Symbol on that object, which isn't part of the type. You'd get a similar error if you did `version["randomString"]`, because that property isn't declared to be part of the type of `Version`.

As another commented has mentioned, you can ignore the error with `$FlowFixMe`. But this code itself might be unsafe, since you're relying on extra symbols being defined on this object but not letting Flow prove it. You could try to model your `Version` type in a way that avoids having to do these dynamic lookups.

(Edit: ah, ok, looks like I spoke too soon. Flow doesn't like using computer symbol keys, even though it in theory could check them. See this issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2928)

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of the lack of support for Symbols, in the meantime `// $FlowFixMe` solves the issue. I hope Facebook solves that soon.