# Suppressing a Flow error regarding Symbol.iterator

Tags: javascript, iterator, flowtype

The following correct code produces a Flow error (version 0.93), due to poor Flow support for Symbols:

```
const iterator: Iterator<Item> = items[Symbol.iterator]();
```

```
string [1] is not an array index.

     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_30af1970/core.js
 [1] 90│   static iterator: string; // polyfill '@@iterator'
```

I can see two ways to suppress it, neither of which I am happy with. Should I use one of these (if so, which), or is there a better way? If possible, please explain why.

Add a FixMe comment:

```
// $FlowFixMe
const iterator: Iterator<Item> = items[Symbol.iterator]();
```

or typecast the array to `any`:

```
const iterator: Iterator<Item> = (items: any)[Symbol.iterator]();
```

Answers submitted to [How do I suppress flow symbol errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658271) from two years ago provide no alternatives either.

(I am seeking ways to eliminate the iterator and use a simple loop, but that's tricky, so ignore the possibility for the purposes of this question)

Comment: Unfortunate there was never an answer, I'm dealing with this now too. I'll answer if/when I figure it out.

Comment: Figured out my issue and commented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651963